# Need a reference book on stokes theorem other than rudin

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry

As the title suggests, I am looking for a book (other than Rudin's Mathematical Analysis) that covers differential forms, simplexes, chains, stokes theorem.

Actually I am not familiar with tensor products. So I will like to have a book where forms are introduced without the aid of tensor products.

Comment: Lee, smooth manifolds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these books:

- *Calculus on Manifolds* by Spivak.
- *Geometric approach to differential forms* by Bachman.